# Inconsistent Error Animating Stops in a LinearGradientBrush

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, storyboard

**UPDATE**
I may know What is causing it but I'd still like to understand the Why and if there is a better way to do this.

The cause appears to be the IsAsync="True" on the values being passed into the converter.  I had noticed that the StatusBackgroundColorConverter2 was being called 3 to 4 times for each alarm.

- First time into Convert Method both Value and IsAcknowledge were set to DependencyProperty.UnsetValue.
- The second time the Value property was there but the IsAcknowledged was Unset.
- The third time through both Value and IsAcknowledge were finally set.

So it appears that when the individual Bindings in a MultiBinding are set to Async it means that your Converters Convert Method gets ran anytime any of the bindings change.

I added another binding for debugging of  to see the Item itself.  When Value is changed the Convert Method executed and Value was populated but IsAcknowledged was an UnsetValue even though I could see that IsAcknowledged is set on the actual object.

I can turn the IsAsync off but doing so causes quite a noticeable lag in the UI when status changes.  Is there some way to Turn IsAsync On for the Binding itself and IsAsync Off for the individual Bindings inside it?

**END UPDATE**

I am in a real pickle and desperately trying to understand what the issue is here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I have a critical application that monitors several things and presents Alarm Notifications based on data.

Alarms are displayed in ItemsControls.  Various display attributes such as Background and Foreground Color change based on status.  Some status call for "Blinking" which I implemented as a rolling gradient in the appropriate color based on the status (Yellow, Red, etc).

All of this functionality actually works, however after a while the alarms start throwing the following error:

> 'GradientStops' property value in the path '(0).(1)[1].(2)' points to
>   immutable instance of 'System.Windows.Media.GradientStopCollection'.

The error is swallowed for now, but that alarm no longer works.  One by one they all die this way.  To even recreate this I had to setup data to change the statuses for many alarms back and forth every 5 seconds.  After 30 to 60 seconds it begins to happen.

Rectangle Xaml

```
<Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"    >
                            <Rectangle.Fill  >
                                <MultiBinding UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"  NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True">
                                    <MultiBinding.Converter >
                                        <conv:StatusBackgroundColorConverter2 />
                                    </MultiBinding.Converter>
                                    <Binding Path="Value" IsAsync="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True"  />
                                    <Binding Path="IsAcknowledged" IsAsync="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                            <Rectangle.Style>
                                <Style>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Value="true"  >
                                            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                                <MultiBinding UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                                                    <MultiBinding.Converter>
                                                        <conv:IsBlinkingStatusConverter />
                                                    </MultiBinding.Converter>
                                                    <Binding Path="Value" IsAsync="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                                                    <Binding Path="IsAcknowledged" IsAsync="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </DataTrigger.Binding>
                                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="RollingGradient"  />
                                                <BeginStoryboard Name="RollingGradient">
                                                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                                        <DoubleAnimation FillBehavior="Stop" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Offset)" From="-.1" To="1.3" By=".1" Duration="0:0:3"/>
                                                        <DoubleAnimation FillBehavior="Stop" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Offset)" From=".6" To="1.3" By=".1" Duration="0:0:3"/>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="RollingGradient"  />
                                            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                        </DataTrigger>                                             
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Rectangle.Style>
                        </Rectangle>
```

Converters:

```
public class StatusBackgroundColorConverter2 : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values != null && values.Length > 1 && values[0] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue && values[1] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
        {
            Brush brush;
            int status = System.Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
            bool acknowledged = System.Convert.ToBoolean(values[1]);
            bool blink = blinkingStatuses.Contains(status) && !acknowledged; 

            Color c = new Color();

            if (status < 0 || status > 12)
                c = Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255);
            else if (status == 0)
                c = Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0); 
            else if (status < 5)
                c = Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 80);
            else if (status < 9)
                c = Color.FromRgb(255, 153, 0);
            else if (status < 13)
            {
                c = Color.FromRgb(255, 38, 0);
            }

            if (blink)
            { 
                LinearGradientBrush lgb = new LinearGradientBrush();
                lgb.StartPoint = new Point(0, 0.5);
                lgb.EndPoint = new Point(1, 0.5); 
                Color backcolor = Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0);

                lgb.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop { Color = backcolor, Offset = 0 });
                lgb.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop { Color = c, Offset = -.1 });
                lgb.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop { Color = backcolor, Offset = .6 });

                brush = lgb;
            }
            else
            // I was returning a SolidColorBrush if status was not blinking, but I changed to gradient brush and 
            // and just kept the colors the same hoping having the stops there would address the issue.  It didn't.
            // brush = new SolidColorBrush(c);
            {
                var b = new LinearGradientBrush();
                b.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop { Color = c, Offset = 0});
                b.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop { Color = c, Offset = -.1 });
                b.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop { Color = c, Offset = .6 });

                brush = b;
            }

            return brush;
        }
        return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255));   
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

    private int[] blinkingStatuses = new int[] { 3, 4, 7, 8, 11, 12 };
}
```

The hardest part for me is that it works just fine at first.  If it was going to fail why doesn't it fail first time?  I would sincerely appreciate any input towards this at all.  I've got to come up with something and I feel like I have very little to go on.

Thanks!

Comment: Whoa, dude you're way over complicating it. A simple ColorAnimation with a AutoReverse or RepeatBehavior would cut all that clutter and ditch your immutable errors, turning all those lines into like one.

Comment: I thought I tried that in the past but you couldn't dynamically set the colors in the Color Animation.  Because the color might be flashing Yellow or Orange or Red I couldn't hard set the To value.  So I looking at doing a sort of "Red Alert" rolling gradient for the animation which they liked.

Comment: Give me an example of what your talking about so I can visualize if you can and I'll offer ya some alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to my issue here was in using Multi-Value Converter with Asynchronous Bindings.  Take the following for example:

```
<MultiBinding UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                                                <MultiBinding.Converter>
                                                    <conv:IsBlinkingStatusConverter />
                                                </MultiBinding.Converter>
                                                <Binding Path="Value" IsAsync="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                                                <Binding Path="IsAcknowledged" IsAsync="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                                            </MultiBinding>
```

I assumed rather incorrectly that the Convert Function in my Multi-Value Converter would execute only once after all of the parameter values were available and it had what it needed.  This is NOT the case.

What I found instead was that for every one item in my collection my Convert method was being called 3 times.

The first time all of my parameters were DependencyProperty.UnsetValue.
The second time Value was set but IsAcknowledged was DependencyProperty.UnsetValue.
The third time both properties were set.

Without specific logic in the Value Converter to return a Binding.DoNothing it was executing with incomplete data twice and then one last time with the all the parameters.  So your results are basically Bad, Bad, Good.  When the system is not under load this happens very fast so you don't notice it.  However under load the interval between the calls gets just a little longer.  The longer it remains in a bad state the larger the likely hood that something else will act upon in that invalid state.

I tried taking specifying default values and even taking out the IsAsync attributes.  While it did work it caused noticeable delays whenever the screen would update.  Putting them back in and implementing logic to look for all the necessary values before executing the logic worked very well.